# Java copyOfRange result error

Tags: java

Here is the source code

```
class App {
public static void main(String[] args){

    int[] x = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int[] xcopy = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(x,0,3);

    System.out.println(xcopy);
}
}
```

The code compiles without error, but the result is this:

`[I@659e0bfd`

when it should be:

`0,1,2`

Why isn't this working? or more interestingly, where did the initial result come from?

Comment: Hint: this is nothing to do with copyOfRange. `System.out.println(x)` would do the same thing. As would `System.out.println(new int[] {1, 2, 3});`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print out an array. You should be using a loop to iterate through the array and print out each individual int

Comment: or there is a method `Arrays.toString(myArray)` to achieve this